# FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP with filter_input_array

Tags: php

To the following code

```php
function register(): int
{
    $filter = array(
        'email' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
        'password' => array(
            'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
            'options' => array('regexp' => '/^(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])\S{8,}$/')
        )
    );
    $filter['password_bis'] = &$filter['password'];

    $user_data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filter, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
    var_dump($user_data);
    return 1;
}
```

I submitted POST data

```php
array('email' => 'my@email.net', 'password' => 'wrong')
```

The email filter works as expected. But, not the password one.

```php
array(2) {
  ["email"]=>
  string(12) "my@email.net"
  ["password"]=>
  string(5) "wrong"
}
```

Any ideas of what I missed?

EDIT:
 I'm using php7. Even the function `filter_var_array(array('email' => 'test@ok.com', 'password' => 'wrong'), $filter, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE)` doesn't work. But, with php5 it's ok. Perhaps it's a bug from php7?

Comment: You'll have to explain what makes a password invalid for you. That seems to be a pet peeve that varies across webmasters: some hate spaces, others hate long passwords, others hate non-English characters...

Comment: Well, password must match with regex, it's not the case.